# Searching in Elasticsearch with a list by field

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I want ES to return me results that matches a field called `code` that is contained in a list.

I have a list, var `codeList = '12A, 13B, 15J'`. My ES documents all have a field named `code`. I want to search for all documents that matches the values in codeList.

Document:

```
hits:[
{
 ._source:{
     title: 'Lion',
     codes: ['12A']
   }
},
{
 ._source:{
     title: 'Lion',
     codes: ['13B, 12A']
   }
},
{
 ._source:{
     title: 'Lion',
     codes: ['15J, XXX']
   }
},
]
```

I want only the first two documents returned, not the 3rd because the codeList contains those values.

I have

```
codeList = results.split(',')// results=12A, 13B, 15J
 var data = {
      size: 999 
      q: 'code:'
    };
```

The document code field will always be a list, like: `['A1','B2']`. Order doesn't matter. It should match only if *all* of the documents' `codes` field is present in the codeList array.

Comment: Just to be clear, let's say you have an array [A,B,C], and documents with code like {[A], [A,B], [A,B,C], [A,D], [D]} - can you please tell us what documents should match? only the groups that are proper set?

Comment: the document code field will always be a list, like: ['A1','B2']. Order doesnt matter. It should match only if the document's codes field is present in the codeList array.

Comment: I forgot to add: it should match if only ALL of the code or codes in the codes array is present in the codeList. It should not return if there is a code in codes that's not present in codeList.

Answer (score 0):

> Disclaimer - I hope there is a better solution for this, but when I faced the
>   problem the following was the only way I could find

You can't perform a [Search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html) for that.

You can perform a [Scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html).

Guideline - The script will iterate each document and will take the array of the document, will perform a check that your main list contains all the elements in the document's list.

I achieved the following by using [groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) script (not dynamic scripting)

You should create the script file:

```
elastic_search_folder\config\scripts\myscript.groovy
```

Your script file should look like that:

```
// Main array
def input = input

// Document's array
def document_input = doc['codes']

input.containsAll(document_input)
```

All that left for you is to build the query that will run the script - I recommend you reading about the elastic search scripting (especially groovy).